# How to implement heap for fast searching?

Tags: data-structures, computer-science, heap

I need to implement a heap, and search for various values in the heap.

The traditional implementation of a heap is a single array, but this is slow to search. I believe the best we can do is linear search.

I believe there is an implementation of heaps as two arrays, which makes it easier to search. However, I have never seen how this works.

Could anyone explain and/or provide a reference for how to do this?

Comment: Heaps aren't really good at searching, because you can't always narrow a branch down. If you're looking for `10` and the root's value is `100` and its children are `80` and `75`, `10` could be in either branch. The worst case will always be linear unless you have extra information. You're better off with a search tree or a sorted list you can apply binary search to, if you want any semblance of performance.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about what you’re aiming to do with the heap that supports searching? There may be an alternative approach that doesn’t require tweaking the heap.

Comment: Where did you learn that heaps would be good for *searching*? How did you come to believe there is a 2-array heap that makes search easier? Where is this belief based on?

Comment: @templatetypedef I start with a collection of `C` `k` elements. As the program runs, elements keep getting added or deleted from this collection. `k` is bounded above by some `n`, which I know the value of. Every time `C` changes, I need to know the maximum element of `C`. So my solution is to heapify `C` at the beginning. Then, as I add and delete elements, I update the heap. Do you think there is a better way to do this?

Comment: @Welbog I figured out a way to search heaps effectively. Let `1 <= k <= n` and say you are trying to heapify `k` numbers from the set `{0, ..., n-1}`. As you create your heap array `heap`, you also create an array `heapindex` with the property that, for `i = 1, 2, ..., k`,   `heap[i] = j iff heapindex[j] = i`. So now if you want to find an element `j` in `heap`, you know that it will be in `heap[ heapindex[j] ]`.

Comment: @trincot Please see my response Welbog.

Comment: If you are using a heap for the set `{0, ..., n-1}`, then drop the heap all together, because then using the second array only is enough for getting a sorted sequence. Heaps are not for that specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are heaps that you can implement with even a single array (no need for two) that support search as well as heap operations (Google the paper "Optimal Worst-Case Operations for Implicit Cache-Oblivious Search Trees"), they are very complex. OTOH, a basic balanced binary search tree supports both search and heap operations, albeit in Ω(n) nodes, rather than a single array. Of course, you can embed those nodes in a single array if you like, but you still need space for pointers.

If that doesn't meet your needs, you might want to constrain the question further.

Comment: I figured out a way to search heaps effectively. Let 1 <= k <= n and say you are trying to heapify k numbers from the set {0, ..., n-1}. As you create your heap array heap, you also create an array heapindex of size `n`, with the property that, for i = 1, 2, ..., k, heap[i] = j iff heapindex[j] = i. So now if you want to find an element j in heap, you know that it will be in heap[ heapindex[j] ].

Answer (score 0):

## Heaps are mostly used for queues implementations

anyway tho, what you can do to use an Heap to sort your array is:

1. insert in a new heap array O(log(n))
2. extracting the Max element (or min element) and put it at the beginning of your array, until the heap array is empty

this way you can implement an heap sort

You can have a Max oriented Heap or a Min oriented Heap, depending what value you want to dequeue first.

This is my implementation of 2 functions to insert a value in a Heap Binary Tree and how to delete_max in python.

> keep in mind that Binary Heap trees need to be binary trees, the parent should always be bigger than children and they should be filled from left to right!

---

The array in the example looks like this, if it was a bin heap tree:

```
                                     30

                                  19    25

 
# Binary Heap
import math

#I want to move a BST with Node in an array
# it is a max heap

heap = [30,19,25]


def getLeftChildIndex(i):
    return i*2+1

def getParentindex(i):
    return math.ceil((i-2)/2)

def insert(value, i):
    
    
    parentIndex = getParentindex(i)
    #print("heap[parentIndex]",heap[parentIndex])
    
    if parentIndex < 0:
        return heap
    
    if parentIndex == 0 and value > heap[parentIndex]:
        heap[parentIndex], heap[i]= heap[i],heap[parentIndex]
          
    if value > heap[parentIndex]:
        #swap
        heap[parentIndex], heap[i]= heap[i],heap[parentIndex]
        insert(value, parentIndex)
    return heap
        

heap.append(29)
print(insert(29,len(heap)-1))
    
heap.append(28)
print(insert(28,len(heap)-1))

heap.append(40)
print(insert(40,len(heap)-1))

heap.append(51)
print(insert(51,len(heap)-1))



def delete_max(i=0):
    #swap the 1st elem of arr with the higher of the children and so on
    
    #get indexes
    li = getLeftChildIndex(i)
    ri = getLeftChildIndex(i)+1
   
    #just check if left is out of range cause if left does not exist means that it is the last leaf
    if li >= len(heap)-1:
        heap.pop(i)
        return heap
    
    left = heap[li]
    right = heap[ri]

    if left > right:
        heap[i] = left
        delete_max(getLeftChildIndex(i))
    else:
        heap[i] = right
        delete_max(getLeftChildIndex(i)+1)
   
    return heap
    
print(delete_max())
print(delete_max())
print(delete_max())
print(delete_max())
print(delete_max())
print(delete_max())
print(delete_max())
```